# How to run 2 separate apps in PM2?

Tags: node.js, pm2

Right now I am using pm2 to run a node server app. I do that with `pm2 start npm`. This seems to be independent of the current directory.

I found some mentions online to use `pm2 start npm --name "app_name" -- start`. However, no matter what name I specify and directory I am inside, it always starts the same app.

Due to the nature of node, I don't run a single .js file and just type `npm start` in the current directory.

Edit: From my understanding, the problem seems to be that pm2 always starts /usr/bin/npm (Starting /usr/bin/npm in fork_mode (1 instance). So the --name flag doesn't matter much, ie. I can get a list of the same app with different names, and this app is node app A and sometimes node app B. I am kinda lost

Comment: can you give details of what you are doing? like your app folder path then what exact command you are running. What do you mean independant of current directory. Add these information in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is happening is you have a PM2 app named `npm`, thus the confusion. You can list pm2 apps with `pm2 ls`

First, remove it using :

```
pm2 del npm
```

Then, start a new app, naming it :

```
pm2 start npm --name "app_name" -- start
```

Then, the second app (in the other directory) with :

```
pm2 start npm --name "app_name2" -- start
```

Comment: Okay, however I get "Starting /usr/bin/npm in fork_mode (1 instance)" after each command. I am not actually specifying which node app to run..

Answer (score 0):

You can run Multiple apps using PM2 just follow below steps:

Firstly enter into directory **A** and start it on PM2 `pm2 start server.js --name app-name`

Save this in PM2 using `pm2 save`

Now to run other app you need enter into directory **B** and start app using 
`pm2 start server.js --name app-name`

Save this process as well, and now check PM2 list using `pm2 ls`

Comment: Hmm, my start command (in 'npm start') is: "start": "webpack --watch --config webpack.config.js --display-error-details ", so I guess just running server.js won't work?